# What is the word for the universe a movie lives in?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, in the movie The Invention of Lying, nobody can lie. So a rule is created that states that nobody can lie in this universe, and the story is constructed with this rule in mind.

So a universe is created which respects this rule.

Every movie creates its own universe, whether it's characters that don't exist in our universe or events that didn't happen in our universe.

What do you call the universe a movie lives in?

Comment: I call it a "plot contrivance" that depends on "the suspension of disbelief" on the part of the audience.

Comment: If you want a simple word everyone can understand: *setting*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called the ***diegetic universe*** or just ***diegesis***:

> 1. the telling of a story by a narrator who summarizes events in the plot and comments on the conversations, thoughts, etc., of the characters.
> 2. the sphere or *world* in which these narrated events and other elements occur.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/diegesis)

This word is rather common in film and literary criticism.

Comment: +1, perfect match! For a more popular word, consider "premises" of the universe.

Answer (score 2):

"Fictional universe" is the formal term I've seen used most often:

[Wikipedia Fictional Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_universe)

However, in the fan-fiction world, "universe" or even the shortened form "'verse," with or without the initial apostrophe, are more colloquial--fanfiction writers wouldn't say "fictional universe."

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the term:
a film's CANON.
ex:
"The two films Alien Covenant and Prometheus completely deviated from CANON established in the first film".
OR
"George Lucas making Darth Vader/Anakin  the creator of C3-PO is completely antithetical to established CANON of the Star Wars Universe".